# How can I adjust the brightness of a picture using a trackbar_scroll (C# winform)?

Tags: c#, winforms

I was wondering if you can help me. I got this project in C# class: to adjust the brightness or contrast of a picture using a trackbar. I tried searching online but I couldn't find anything useful. All of the solutions found on internet use ColorMatrix and I can't use it because my project won't accept it (idk why). It gives me the following error: "The type or namespace name 'ColorMatrix' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly refference?)".
Can somebody please help me?
The following code is the one I was trying to use:

```
public static Bitmap AdjustBrightness(Bitmap Image, int Value)
{
  Bitmap TempBitmap = Image;
  float FinalValue = (float)Value / 255.0f;
  Bitmap NewBitmap = new Bitmap(TempBitmap.Width, TempBitmap.Height);
  Graphics NewGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(NewBitmap);
  float[][] FloatColorMatrix ={
    new float[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    new float[] {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    new float[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
    new float[] {FinalValue, FinalValue, FinalValue, 1, 1}
  };
  ColorMatrix NewColorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(FloatColorMatrix);
  ImageAttributes Attributes = new ImageAttributes();
  Attributes.SetColorMatrix(NewColorMatrix);
  NewGraphics.DrawImage(TempBitmap,
    new Rectangle(0, 0, TempBitmap.Width, TempBitmap.Height),
    0, 0, TempBitmap.Width, TempBitmap.Height,GraphicsUnit.Pixel, Attributes);
  Attributes.Dispose();
  NewGraphics.Dispose();
  return NewBitmap;
}
```

Comment: [How to use a slider control to adjust the brightness of a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55663285/7444103) (note that this is *simplified* method, Brightness & Contrast adjustments are actually a *little bit* more complex) -- You can of course limit the range of values so the adjusted colors won't turn the image into its *negative* (unless you want it, that is).

Comment: "are you missing a using directive" tends to be an accurate error message, ensure you put `using System.Drawing.Imaging;` at the top of the source file.

Comment: When a `using directive` is missing, just put the cursor inside the keyword(s) that is/are underlined in red and press ALT+ENTER (or click the light bulb). Visual Studio will determine the missing import for you and propose some solutions, popping up a menu.