# Dark mode map in GMap.NET

Tags: c#, winforms, openstreetmap, darkmode, gmap.net

I'm developing an application using C# and WinForms, with [GMap.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GMap.NET.WinForms) library.

Would anyone know any way to set the **dark mode** for the map?

I'm currently using the OpenStreet map:
`map.MapProvider = OpenStreetMapProvider.Instance`

I've looked in the documentation but I didn't find anything. When using Google map, it is possible to set color parameters in CSS, but I didn't find a way to define a CSS or theme directly in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMap.NET provides three predefined rendering modes:

- the default one, using the colors defined by the Provider
- An inverted mode, which sets the colors to negative => `[GMapControl].NegativeMode`
- A gray-scale mode, where all colors are converted to a scale of gray; white is white => `[GMapControl].GrayScaleMode`

These rendering modes use a [ColorMatrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix) object to define the amount of color per channel.

It also provides means to specify a custom ColorMatrix, setting the `[GMapControl].ColorMatrix` property.

The inverted matrix is ~like this:

```
var matrixInverted = new ColorMatrix(new float[][] {
    new float[] { -1,  0,  0,  0,  0},
    new float[] {  0, -1,  0,  0,  0},
    new float[] {  0,  0, -1,  0,  0},
    new float[] {  0,  0,  0,  1,  0},
    new float[] {  1,  1,  1,  0,  1}
});
```

The gray-scale matrix is ~like this (my interpretation):

```
var matrixGray = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]
{
    new float[] { .2126f, .2126f, .2126f, 0, 0 },
    new float[] { .7152f, .7152f, .7152f, 0, 0 },
    new float[] { .0722f, .0722f, .0722f, 0, 0 },
    new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
    new float[] { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 }
});
```

If the negative mode is not exactly what you're looking for, you could invert the colors of the gray-scale ColorMatrix:

```
var matrixGrayInverted = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]
{
    new float[] { -.2126f, -.2126f, -.2126f, 0, 0 },
    new float[] { -.7152f, -.7152f, -.7152f, 0, 0 },
    new float[] { -.0722f, -.0722f, -.0722f, 0, 0 },
    new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
    new float[] { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 }
});
```

Then set the property:

```
[GMapControl].ColorMatrix = matrixGrayInverted;
```

About the usage of these matrices, see the notes in these questions:

[How can I gray-out a disabled PictureBox used as Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61584671/7444103)
[How to use a slider control to adjust the brightness of a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55663285/7444103)
[How to apply a fade transition effect to Images using a Timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61293719/7444103)
[Replacing colour of an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47529000/7444103)