# How to change only the contrast of an image?

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms

I have a picturebox and a trackbar with range (-100 to 100, 0 being the default). I'm using the following method to change the contrast of the image:

```
public static Bitmap AdjustContrast(this Image image, sbyte contrastValue)
{
    var contrast = contrastValue / 100.0f;
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    using (var attributes = new ImageAttributes())
    {
        float[][] matrix = {
            new float[] {contrast, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0, contrast, 0, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0, 0, contrast, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            new float[] {1, 1, 1, 1, 1} //Here is the problem
        };

        var colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(matrix);

        attributes.ClearColorMatrix();
        attributes.SetColorMatrix(colorMatrix);

        g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
            0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

But the contrast is not being changed. The image turns black most of the time. The problem is the last item in the array where usually the brightness value is passed. As I just want to change only contrast what should the values of the last array be?

Comment: [How to use a slider control to adjust the brightness of a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55663285/7444103)

Comment: [How to apply a fade transition effect to Images using a Timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61293719/7444103) (Matrix definition)

Comment: @Jimi Problem seems to be fixed now as I changed the contrast range from -100 to 200 and type to `int`. However, sliding back to the negative values will result in a black image. Is this normal?

Comment: Of course it's *normal*. Contrast below `0` (as defined in the Identity Matrix), generates the negative of an image, visible when the brightness is increased. You can see the effect in the first post